# What is "⿰糹"? (Some variant of 级?)

Tags: character-identification

Saw this at a store the other day:

> [image]

I believe the middle character's components can be broken down like:

> ⿰糹

I'm assuming it's just some variant of 级 but I can't find any evidence to support that. Where is this used? The product is from Thailand but they don't use Chinese characters in Thailand.

Maybe it's just *fanti* 級 stretched out - making it harder to recognize.

Ideas?

Comment: Isn't it 超级米粉 ? Like "super rice noodles"

Comment: Yes, the way "健力超级米粉" is arranged, is  for  graphic effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right hand side is not 「」, it is the standard Taiwanese and Korean shape of 「及」. Maybe you're accustomed to seeing one of the other locale shapes.

[image: locale shapes of 及]